# Convert NSDecimalNumber to NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, md5, nsdecimalnumber

I use this code to get md5 string hash

```
- (NSString *) md5:(NSString *) input
{
    const char *cStr = [input UTF8String];
    unsigned char digest[16];
    CC_MD5( cStr, strlen(cStr), digest ); // This is the md5 call

    NSMutableString *output = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];

    for(int i = 0; i < CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
        [output appendFormat:@"%02x", digest[i]];

    return  output;
}
```

When i do this it work perfect

```
[self md5:@"mystring"];
```

But when i make this

```
[self md5:userId];
```

i have an error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSDecimalNumber UTF8String]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x61a7080'

userId is an NSString

```
NSString *userId; @property(retain,nonatomic) NSString *userId;
```

but it contaile facebook user id , something like "3309843"
i tried

```
[self md5:[userId stringValue]]];
```

and i still have the same error

**UPDATE**
i tried this

```
[self md5:@"980232376"];
```

and still have the same error, i think the problem is the method md5. I can't get md5 of a string of numbers ?

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like it actually isn't a string you have there, if you are parsing json to get it it most likely is a NSNumber and not a NSString. All the JSON parsers I have tried so far converts numbers to NSNumber. I think a quick test to see could be to just change the property to NSNumber and then:

```
[self md5:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", userId]];
```

Comment: i'am sorry, there was an NSLog(@"hash %@",[self md5:uiserId];  I had not seen, it work perfect , thank you